# why csv is consuming more file size in my unix script?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, ksh, database

I'm using [this](http://pastebin.com/3sN3sDPR) unix script which it is fetching records in the form of csv. I have a SQL query used for this purpose. It contains below information

```
SET PAGESIZE 5000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 2000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET UNDERLINE OFF
```

Is it due to `PAGESIZE` it is consuming more space?

The script returns 4MB of CSV(`OBTM.csv`) file whereas if I'm converting the same to (`OBTM.xlsx`) it is 48KB.

Kindly clarify my query

Comment: What 'unix' script? Is this bash, ksh, zsh what? Could you give us an example of the `.csv` and `.xlsx` files generated? How are you converting? Are you on Unix,Linux, which one?

Comment: @terdon 

I'm using Sun solaris Unix server which is ksh shell. I can't attach generated files.

usppodivximf00(usoponshximf00):/vol01/sites/provisioning/IG> uname
SunOS
usppodivximf00(usoponshximf00):/vol01/sites/provisioning/IG>



usppodivximf00(usoponshximf00):/vol01/sites/provisioning/IG> echo $0
-ksh
usppodivximf00(usoponshximf00):/vol01/sites/provisioning/IG>

Comment: Please postthe details on how you are converting to csv and to xlsx and, if possible, a sample of the two files, yes. Either [edit] your question to post a few lines of each file or use a service like pastebin.com.

Comment: Thanks for the script, however, that does not show the part where the csv and xlsx files are generated. If I understand correctly, that is being done by `/vol01/sites/provisioning/IG/46762.sql` or perhaps `count.sh`. Also, you might want to delete the email addresses from your script in pastebin to avoid SPAM.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, each field in each record is space-padded to the field width. We'd need to see the query but instead of `select * from table`, you may need

```
select rtrim(field1) || ',' || rtrim(field2) || ',' || rtrim(field3) -- ...
```

Alternately, run the csv file through a sed script to trim excessive whitespace:

```
sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]\+,/,/g' OBTM.csv
```

Comment: @ terdon thanks for providing the new information about pastebin. I 'm sharing the pastebin link here.
http://pastebin.com/3sN3sDPR
@glenn I will try removing space. Kindly have a view on the script

Comment: @terdon/glenn ... I'm providing SQL query in this link...Kindly review and let me know if u need any information
http://pastebin.com/pQnm4cRA